# mongoose keys of returns model is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am having a weird problem with mongoose where I want to specifically access a model's keys.

```js
export const exportUsers = async () => {
    const users = await User.find();
    const headers = ["firstName","lastName"]

    users.forEach((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        // this shows:
        // {
        //    firstName: "zac",
        //    lastName: "taylor"
        // }

        console.log(user.firstName); // undefined; nothing
        
        // if i log the keys for the user:
        console.log(Object.keys(user));

        // i get this weird stuff:
        // [
        //   '$parent',
        //   '$isSingleNested',
        //   '$__',
        //   'isNew',
        //   'errors',
        //   '$locals',
        //   '$op',
        //   '_doc',
        //   '$init'
        // ]

    })

    return csvify.create(exportData, headers, 'Users-List.csv');
}
```

but logging the whole model shows it's there, but with `Object.keys` it is not there...

how do I just directly access `user.firstName` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are getting Mongoose objects, not simply JSON data.

If you want only pure JSON data, use lean() :

```
 const users = await User.find().lean();
```

Comment: You're a G jeremy

Comment: Oh I've just pulled my hair out before you :)